# How to write a regular expression pattern that is capable of validating URIs?

Tags: .net, regex

How does one go about authoring a ***Regular Expression*** that matches against all strings that are valid URIs, while failing to match against all strings that are invalid URIs?

To be specific about what I am referencing when I say URI, I have added a link below for the most current URI RFC standard. It defines the entity that I want to validate using a regular expression.

I don't need it to be able to parse the URI. I just need a regular expression for validating.

The **.Net Regular Expression Format** is preferred. (.Net V1.1)

##### My Current Solution:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9+.-]+):(//([a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]*)@)?([a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=]+)(:(\\d*))?(/?[a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/]+)?(\\?[a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]+)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]+)?$(:(\\d*))?(/?[a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/]+)?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]+)?(\#[a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]+)?$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This site looks promising: http://snipplr.com/view/6889/regular-expressions-for-uri-validationparsing/

They propose following regex:

```
/^([a-z0-9+.-]+):(?://(?:((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)@)?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)(?::(\d*))?(/(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?|(/?(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})+(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?)(?:\?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?(?:#((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?$/i
```

Comment: I used this trick in PHP. For PHP coders, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Comment: Doesn't work for example "ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one"

Comment: @msavara right. it's probably best to use bdukes answer!

Comment: Scheme names, AFAIK, cannot start with `+`, `-`, or `.`, but only with an alphabetic character. See [RFC3986 (section 3.1)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3).

Comment: That one is pretty good, but it misses urls with `email:password`. e.g `scheme://user@example.com:pass@exaple.com/`. See @Lostfields response if you need to catch those.

Comment: @HuBeZa we probably shouldn't be using regexes for this anyway. This was a long time ago. I'd use the library function bdukes mentioned.

Answer (score 30):

Does [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) work for you?

Comment: +1 This is the only correct answer. Regex is not the correct tool for the job. I always wonder how standards compliant and secure parsing an Uri with regex can be. Dealing with internationalized (unicode) domains? Encodings that obfuscate the true path? Fault-tolerant? Tested? Just use the .net framework!

Answer (score 20):

The [URI specification says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B):

> *The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a well-formed URI reference into its components.*
>
> `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?`

(I guess that's the same regex as in the STD66 link given in another answer.)

But *breaking-down* is not *validating*. To correctly validate a URI, one would have to translate the [BNF for URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) to a regex. While some BNFs *cannot* be expressed as regular expressions, I think with this one it *could* be done. But it shouldn't be done - it would be a huge mess. It's better to use a library function.

Answer (score 10):

The best regex I came up with according to RFC 3986 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) was the following:

[image: Flow diagram of regex using https://regexper.com]

```
// named groups
/^(?<scheme>[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]+):(?<authority>\/\/(?<user>[^@]+@)?(?<host>[a-z0-9.\-_~]+)(?<port>:\d+)?)?(?<path>(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@])+(?:\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@])*)*|(?:\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@])+)*)?(?<query>\?(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@]|[/?])+)?(?<fragment>\#(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@]|[/?])+)?$/i

// unnamed groups
/^([a-z][a-z0-9+.-]+):(\/\/([^@]+@)?([a-z0-9.\-_~]+)(:\d+)?)?((?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@])+(?:\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@])*)*|(?:\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@])+)*)?(\?(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@]|[/?])+)?(\#(?:[a-z0-9-._~]|%[a-f0-9]|[!$&'()*+,;=:@]|[/?])+)?$/i
```

capture groups

1. scheme
2. authority
3. userinfo
4. host
5. port
6. path
7. query
8. fragment

Comment: @Teivaz hmm, the fragment part should catch that though; https://regex101.com/r/gilHCG/1

Answer (score 8):

The best and most definitive guide to this I have found is here: [http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html#uri-40) (In answer to your question, see the **URI** table entry)

> All of these rules from RFC3986 are reproduced in Table 2 along with a regular expression implementation for each rule.

A javascript implementation of this is available here: https://github.com/jhermsmeier/uri.regex

For reference, the URI regex is repeated below:

```
# RFC-3986 URI component:  URI
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+\-.]* :                                      # scheme ":"
(?: //                                                          # hier-part
  (?: (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* @)?
  (?:
    \[
    (?:
      (?:
        (?:                                                    (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)    {6}
        |                                                   :: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)    {5}
        | (?:                            [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})? :: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)    {4}
        | (?: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,1} [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})? :: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)    {3}
        | (?: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})? :: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)    {2}
        | (?: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,3} [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})? ::    [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:
        | (?: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,4} [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})? ::
        ) (?:
            [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4} : [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}
          | (?: (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?) \.){3}
                (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
          )
      |   (?: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5} [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})? ::    [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}
      |   (?: (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,6} [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})? ::
      )
    | [Vv][0-9A-Fa-f]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]+
    )
    \]
  | (?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
  | (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*
  )
  (?: : [0-9]* )?
  (?:/ (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )*
| /
  (?:    (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+
    (?:/ (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )*
  )?
|        (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+
    (?:/ (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )*
|
)
(?:\? (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )?   # [ "?" query ]
(?:\# (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )?   # [ "#" fragment ]
```

Comment: sweet mother of all regex, and my co-workers think I'm nuts for using and understanding regex...

Comment: That's absolutely insane! The best example ever to show that, although regexs _are_ useful in a lot of cases, they are _not_ to be used for _everything_. Hammers and nails, screwdrivers and screws.

Answer (score 1):

Are there some specific URIs you care about or are you trying to find a single regex that validates [STD66](http://rfc.net/std0066.html)?

I was going to point you to [this regex](http://www.unix.com.ua/rfc/std0066.html#p50) for parsing a URI.  You could then, in theory, check to see if all of the elements you care about are there.

But I think [bdukes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847#30858) answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

For JS people, check this out the first few lines are all you need if your happy with the tests.  Note this regex is from: [wizard04][1]

```js
//This function

function explodeUri(str) {
    let regexUri = /^([a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*):(?:\/\/((?:(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))(\3)@)?(?=(\[[0-9A-F:.]{2,}\]|(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\5(?::(?=(\d*))\6)?)(\/(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\8)?|(\/?(?!\/)(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\10)?)(?:\?(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\11)?(?:#(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\12)?$/i;
    let match = str.match(regexUri);
    if (!match) {
        throw new Error('Invalid URI');
    }

    return {
        scheme: match[1],           // 1 == scheme
        userinfo: match[4],         // 4 == userinfo
        host: match[5],             // 5 == host
        port: match[6],             // 6 == port
        path: match[7] || match[9], // 7 if it has an authority, 9 if it doesn't
        query: match[11],           // 11 == query
        fragment: match[12]         // 12 == fragment
    };

/*    let { // scheme://user:info@host:port/path?query=val#fragment
        scheme, userinfo, host, port,
        path, query, fragment,
    } = explodeUri(u);                                           */
} ///https://snipplr.com/view/6889?codeview= Thanks bro!

function testUriValidation() {
    const validUrls = [
        'https://www.example.com/path/to/resource?query=value#fragment',
        'ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com:21/path/to/file',
        'http://subdomain.example.co.uk/page?param=value',
        'mailto:user@example.com',
        'tel:+123456789',
        'file:///path/to/file.txt',
        'data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D',
        'https://[2001:db8::1]/path',               // IPv6 address
        'https://user@192.168.0.1',                  // IPv4 address with userinfo
        'http://user:pass@[::1]:8080/path',         // IPv6 with userinfo and port
        'http://example.com/a%20b',                 // URL-encoded path
        'https://example.com/%E2%82%AC100',         // URL-encoded path segment
        'http://example.com?name=John%20Doe',       // URL-encoded query parameter
        'https://example.com#section-3.4',          // URL fragment
        'https://example.com:8080',                 // URL with port
        'https://example.com:8080/path?query=value', // URL with path and query
    ];

    const invalidUrls = [
        'invalid-url',                          // Missing scheme
        'http://www.example.com:8080:',          // Invalid port
        'ftp://user:pass@invalid host/',         // Invalid characters in the host
        'http://[::1]',                          // IPv6 without a scheme
        'https://user@192.168.0.1:invalid',      // Invalid port
        'http://example.com/ path with space',   // Invalid space in the path
        "https://example.com?invalid=query",     // Invalid character in the query
        'ftp://example.com:8080#invalid-fragment', // Invalid character in the fragment
        "http://example.com:8080/path?query#fragment", // Both query and fragment without '='
        "http://:8080/path",                     // Empty authority
        'ftp://user@:21/path',                   // Empty host in authority
        'http://example.com/path?query#fragment%zz', // Invalid percent encoding
        'schema://user:pass@server.db.schema.table:1234?option=value#rowid'
    ];

    const uri = 'https://username:password@www.example.com:8080/path/to/resource?query=value#fragment';

    const explodedUri = explodeUri(uri);

    console.log(explodedUri);

    console.log('Valid URLs:');
    validUrls.forEach((url) => {
        console.log("validationg: ", url)
        try {
            const explodedUri = explodeUri(url);
            console.log('O:', url, explodedUri);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('X', url, 'Error:', error.message);
        }
    });

    console.log('\nInvalid URLs:');
    invalidUrls.forEach((url) => {
        try {
            const explodedUri = explodeUri(url);
            console.log('X:', url, 'Exploded URI:', explodedUri);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('ERROR: ', url, error.message);
        }
    });
}

testUriValidation();
```