# Text Display in PHP

Tags: php

if i stored data in DB which contains urls (for example : Go thorugh this link http://www.google.com).

when i display that data in browser, i want to display that data like " Go through this link http://www.google.com ". but that url which looks like anchor link...

if you didn't get this..open google chat...send some msg to anyone like http://google.com..if u send plain text like http://google.com,but it shows with hyper link..to that url..

i want this functionality in PHP technology...how can we implement this

thanks in advance...

Comment: Are the URL the only data, or is it text containing URL ?

Comment: some times it will be text containing URL and URL only the data.

Answer (score 6):

So, you want to [convert the urls to links in php](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+url+to+link+php)? See the [first result](http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/php_convert_url_to_link.php), or answers to [same question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood this correctly you want to transform URLs in a text to links automatically, without going further into details a crude (very crude) regexp should do it for now:

```
$textWithLinks = preg_replace('#(http|ftp)s?://[^\s]+#i', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $textWithUrls);
```

Comment: for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Comment: and also i have one doubt..
your code is not woring with the www.google.com

Comment: because it requires the URLs to start with http, https, ftp or ftps, this can be circumvented ofc. but needs a more advanced script, I said it was *very crude*

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_href ($text) {
    return preg_replace('/((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])/', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $text);
}
```

Expression taken from http://rickyrosario.com/blog/converting-a-url-into-a-link-in-csharp-using-regular-expressions/