# Can anyone help me with this javascript for validating url in aspx?

Tags: javascript, validation, url

Here's my code -

```
  function Validate_URL(url) {
      var iurl = url.value;
      var v = new RegExp();
      v.compile("/^(((ht|f){1}(tp:[/][/]){1})|((www.){1}))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+$/;");
      if (!v.test(iurl.value)) {
          url.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      }
      return true; 
  }
```

no matter what i put in url, say http://www.abc.com/newpage.html, it returns false. how come?

Answer (score 4):

When you're using the constructor, you don't include the beginning and ending `/`.  In this case, you're not using any dynamic strings, so you can use a JavaScript regex literal.

Thus, it's better to do something like:

```
var v = /pattern/;
```

The `{1}` is always redundant, as are the character classes when you have only one element.  `.` needs to be escaped outside character classes.  There's no reason to special-case www.  It's just one possible subdomain.  I don't know why you have a double / in the character class.  There are other issues, such as allowing `@` and `#` everywhere.  You don't have to escape `+` inside a character class.  You also have a stray semi-colon at the end.

There are numerous other questions about this, including [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url), [Checking for a valid url using Javascript Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740537/checking-for-a-valid-url-using-javascript-regular-expressions), and [url validation using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303872/url-validation-using-javascript).