# Identify a URL Using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Checking for a valid url using Javascript Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740537/checking-for-a-valid-url-using-javascript-regular-expressions)
>   [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

I have a `if` statement that will check if the user entered a URL(HTTP Protocol only), like this:

```
if(/^regexp/.test(url))
```

But how should be this regular expression to check if the text is a URL or not?

Comment: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL

Comment: This has been asked lots of times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of any number of these similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=regex%20url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this little function might help:

```
function isURL(string){
  regEx = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
  return regEx.test(string));
}
```

Let us know if it worked out!

W.