# PHP RegEx for "Website Name"

Tags: php, regex, dns

> #### Duplicate: [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

My goal is create a PHP regex for website name. The regex is for a lead gathering form and should accept any legit kind of website name syntax that someone might enter. After an exhaustive search, I'm surprised that I can't find one out there.

Here are the regex matches that I'm looking for:

- somewebsite.com
- http://somewebsite.com
- http://www.somewebsite.com

AND, it should also match:

- any of the above with a trailing backslash, such as: somewebsite.com/
- subdomains

Comment: You're really talking about the sites' addresses, not their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to tweak it:

```
<?php

$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/';

$url1  = "http://www.somewebsite.com";
$url2  = "https://www.somewebsite.com";
$url3  = "https://somewebsite.com";
$url4  = "www.somewebsite.com";
$url5  = "somewebsite.com";

function valURL($pattern, $url) {

        $return = false;

        if(preg_match($pattern, $url)) {
                $return = true;
        }

        if($return == true) {
                echo "Match URL: <font color='green'>" . $url . "</font><br /><br />";
        } else {
                echo "Try Again: <font color='red'>URL: " . $url . "</font><br /><br />";
        }
}

valURL($pattern, $url1);
valURL($pattern, $url2);
valURL($pattern, $url3);
valURL($pattern, $url4);
valURL($pattern, $url5);

?>
```

Comment: @PhillPafford I linked your answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23567981/976775 Thank you for this Regexp!

Answer (score 9):

No RegEx necessary.

```
$subject = 'example.com';
$part = (stripos($subject, 'http://') === FALSE)  ? 'http://' : '' ;
var_dump(filter_var($part.$subject, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

Comment: You're missing a close paren!

Comment: Note that this is only for PHP 5.2+

Comment: That is very useful, but it doesn't match the following:
somewebsite.com

Comment: Andy, test your code before posting. That results in FALSE. I voted you up though because regex are so overused it's insane.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to benchmark the answers here to prove that regular expressions are not the answer for such simple tasks. Andy Leekman's code is whole 30% to 60% quicker than other answers. He did have a bug, but I fixed that with a line of code. You can view my results below.

Here's the code on which the tests ran.

http://pastie.org/476900

[alt text http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/7821/capturevzh.png](http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/7821/capturevzh.png)

**PS** If anyone elses uses a regular expression to validate a URL I might go mad ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
/^([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+((a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|aero|arpa)|(b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|biz)|(c[acdfghiklmnorsuvxyz]|cat|com|coop)|d[ejkmoz]|(e[ceghrstu]|edu)|f[ijkmor]|(g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|gov)|h[kmnrtu]|(i[delmnoqrst]|info|int)|(j[emop]|jobs)|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|(m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|mil|mobi|museum)|(n[acefgilopruz]|name|net)|(om|org)|(p[aefghklmnrstwy]|pro)|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortvyz]|(t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|travel)|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])$/i
```

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2006/05/08/validating_domain_names

Courtesy of google. It is VERY complex though, so someone else might have a simpler one.

EDIT: Try andy's answer first. If you can find an alternative to a regex, 9/10 the alternative is much better.

Comment: That is very useful, but it doesn't match the following: somewebsite.com

Answer (score -1):

```
^(https?://)?(([0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]: )?[0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-z_!'()-]\.)([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-z]\.[a-z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/?)|(/[0-9a-z_!*'().;?:@&=$,%#-])/?)$
```

Comment: I can't get your code to work. Can you provide a simple usage example?

Comment: $pattern = /^(https?://)?(([0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]: )?[0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-z_!'()-]\.)([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-z]\.[a-z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/?)|(/[0-9a-z_!*'().;?:@&=$,%#-])/?)$/

Comment: Sorry, but still not working for me. This is what I am trying. Any suggestion?
$some_url = 'http://some-url.com';

$pattern = "/^(https?://)?(([0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]: )?[0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-z_!'()-]\.)([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-z]\.[a-z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/?)|(/[0-9a-z_!*'().;?:@&=$,%#-])/?)$/";

 if(preg_match($pattern, $some_url)) {
        echo "valid";
    } else {
        echo "invalid";
    }