# Back end validation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How can I validate text column that it doesn't contain websites, examples can be :

```
www.google.com
google.com
http://gooogle.com
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
https://google.com
```

I want to do this on the front side but on the back end as well. I'm more interested in back end at the moment, as I will deal with the front end later

**Question update:**

Based on example provided by MrYoshiji, I've come up with case that is not covered:

http://rubular.com/r/VGgWyfIt7R

See the `http://www.google.com` in the middle of the text? and it is not matched? That is exactly what I need it to be matched. So I can throw validation error saying you can't put websites.

Comment: Whats your end goal here?

Comment: @DickieBoy I don't want to allow people to paste websites in the text box I'm validating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a strong regexp, credits goes to @PhillPafford ([PHP RegEx for "Website Name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848837/php-regex-for-website-name) If you upvote my answer, please upvote his first!):

```
/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/
```

To see it in action:

http://rubular.com/r/GOHHrucCdX

---

**UPDATE:**

This one will find the names anywhere in the text:

```
/(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?/
```

Note that I removed the `^` at the start and the `$` at the end to make it work within a text:

Rubular source:

> ^ Start of line
>
> $ End of line

http://rubular.com/r/iEVzfv2U3O

---

@GandalfStormCrow noticed that the following is matched:

```
Since I was little.My first dog
                #^^^
```

The only way I see to solve this issue would be to replace `little.My` with `little. My`:

```
text.gsub(/\w\.[A-Z]/) { |matched_string| matched_string.gsub('.', '. ') }
```

See it in action:

```
1.9.3p489 :018 > text = "hello my name is robert.My dog"
 => "hello my name is robert.My dog" 
1.9.3p489 :019 > text.gsub(/\w\.[A-Z]/) { |matched_string| matched_string.gsub('.', '. ') }
 => "hello my name is robert. My dog"
```

Comment: it works well for domain matching, but when I put google.com in the middle of your text. It doesn't match and that is what I'm looking for, please see this http://rubular.com/r/VGgWyfIt7R

Comment: This regex lets " google.com" pass. (backticks dont work with a space in them.)

Comment: That's obviously why you call a `.strip` before testing it ...... You don't want users to save any input with 1 or more spaces before, do you?

Comment: Downvote explanation please? @DickieBoy is that you?

Comment: @MrYoshiji nope not me

Comment: @MrYoshiji this regex seems to be overly eager. In the sentence `since I was little.My first dog` little.My is recognized as a url, can you fix this please?

Comment: This part, `little.my` is a possible domain name. Only a human eye could make the difference. The only way I see to fix this issue would be to replace all point followed by a upcase changed to the same with a space between them. It's hacky, I know, but I don't see any other way to do it...

Comment: can you make it at least that it be `little.` followed by lowercase. I think that would be enought distinction. `Where little.my` is domain name and `little.My` is not

Comment: I updated my answer in consequence ;) Hope this one is good enough in your case!

Answer (score 0):

in your model add:

```
validates_format_of :your_column, without: /\A((http(s)?:)?\/\/(www)?.)?(www.)?[a-zA-Z]*.com\z/
```

[Here's where I crafted the Regex](http://rubular.com/r/vr2g13lCk2)

Comment: Reading between the lines of the question. What about google.co.uk?

Comment: What about domain names with digits?

Comment: @MrYoshiji i try not to :P

Answer (score -1):

I see many have taken the regex approach to this but maybe you'd like to create a simple blacklist. Something like:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  BLACKLIST = [
    'google.com'
  ]

  validate :disallow_blacklisted_urls

  private
  def disallow_blacklisted_urls
    BLACKLIST.each do |blacklisted_url|
      if my_field && my_field.include?(blacklisted_url)
        errors.add(:my_field, "must not contain #{blacklisted_url}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The reason I'd go this way is that you can easily add more urls (facebook.com, twitter.com) and it will still work and be clear after a year of not seeing the code while the regex is too cryptic for my aging eyes (and brain :-)). Also if you don't want to check the whole blacklist every time, you can add a break into the core condition of the validation method but I think the user will have a better feedback like this.