# Regex for file names, with no url?

Tags: php, regex, url, path, filenames

How can I write a regex which will replace any file name, with it's folder path, but wouldn't match url? and wouldn't match ***in*** url? For example it should match:

```
/images/something.png
content/scripts/myscript.js
image.gif
/1.jpg
```

But should **not** match:

```
http://www.google.com/images/something.png
www.google.com/scripts/myscript.js
http://site.com/?img=/image.png
http://site.com/?img=/scripts/somescript.js
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is imposible since this is also a valid directory name?

```
www.google.com/scripts/myscript.js
```

I guess only http:// could be filtered.

I don't know what you're planning to do, but maybe you could use file_exists() to check if it's a file on ur filesystem.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url) tells us how to filter a url with regex:

```
$text = preg_replace("
  #((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie",
  "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4'",
  $text
);
```

but it also states that you actually should use the filter_var() function

```
var_dump(filter_var('example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Comment: well say it's not a vaild directory name.

Comment: Alon, you'll first have to provide a definition of an invalid directory is (in your book). We can't read your mind. Is a directory invalid when it has two `.`'s in it? Is it invalid when it ends with `.com`? Etc. etc.

Comment: www.google.com is a valid directory name on Windows 95 (!) and newer, and on all modern Unix-y systems (OS X, Linux) also.