# Validating a URL in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a basic regular expression for validating a url, such that:

- Both http:// and http://www. are allowed (and the same thing with https:// and https://www.).
- All common tld like .com, .net. .org, .cc, .my, etc are allowed.
- Things like http://site.com/dir/dir2/page.html etc are allowed
- Only characters allowed in a url are allowed (such as alphanumeric chars, ?_-.& etc)

Basically something which will check if http:// or https:// is contained, and that at least one tld such as .com, .net, .[something] is contained.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

check out this post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use php's [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

There are good examples on [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
var_dump( filter_var( 'http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) );
```

Comment: Could you please turn this into a real answer so the core of the message is actually here. As it is now it's just a link answer and they're being edited or deleted these days.