# How to check if a given value is a valid URL

Tags: php, validation, url

I need some function to check is the given value is a url.

I have code:

```
<?php
$string = get_from_db();
list($name, $url) = explode(": ", $string);
if (is_url($url)) {
    $link = array('name' => $name, 'link' => $url);
} else {
    $text = $string;
}
// Make some things
?>
```

Comment: See if this works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390275/php-regex-for-validating-a-url

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: Not a dupe - those two are asking for a regex, whereas this one is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running PHP 5 (and you should be!), just use [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
function is_url($url)
{
    return filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false;
}
```

Addendum: as [the PHP manual entry for `parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) (and @Liutas in his comment) points out:

> This function is ***not*** meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted, **parse_url()** tries its best to parse them correctly.

For example, `parse_url()` considers a query string as part of a URL. However, a query string is *not* entirely a URL. The following line of code:

```
var_dump(parse_url('foo=bar&baz=what'));
```

Outputs this:

```
array(1) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(16) "foo=bar&baz=what"
}
```

Comment: You can also specify some options (path or query required): http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: Definitely the best solution. My current project contains a really long regex to check for valid URLs, and tomorrow it's going to be replaced with this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this is what I searching for.

Answer (score 3):

use `parse_url` and check for false

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
   [scheme] => http
   [host] => hostname
   [user] => username
   [pass] => password
   [path] => /path
   [query] => arg=value
   [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: but in manula it sai: "This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly. "

Comment: Beyond this the best way to validate an URL is to make a HTTP request and see if the response is valid.

Comment: I cant do this because this can be sensitive url

Answer (score 0):

You can check if [ParseUrl](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php) returns false.