# Validate Url using regexp

Tags: php, regex, url

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)
>   [PHP regex for validating a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390275/php-regex-for-validating-a-url)

I am using

```
(((?:http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/\?=_#&%~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\?=_#&%~-]+)+)|(www(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\?=_#&%~-]+){2,}))
```

to validate URL in my script.

But my friend told me there is a problem with this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/example(200)aaaa.rar
```

How can I add "`(`" and "`)`" to my regexp statement?

Are there another characters should I put in my regexp?

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: According to your regex, www.foo.#%~ is a valid URL. Whatever language you're using probably already has a URL validator that works better.

Comment: [This question has a LOT of possible duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+url+regexp)

Comment: @Paul : It doesn't work http://regexr.com?2simr

Comment: What doesn't work? I didn't make any suggestions just pointed out a possible duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i recommend this site: http://regexlib.com/
Click Browse at the top and select Uri button.

To answer your question though, `(((?:http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/\?=#&%~-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\?=#&%~-]+)+)|(www(.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\?=_#&%~-\\)\\(]+){2,}))`

Note the `\)` and `\(` towards the end. They must be escaped (prefixed with `\\`) as these are characters used for grouping within regex.

Comment: It doesn't work http://regexr.com?2simo

Comment: That doesn't take into account all those (unfortunately) now valid internationalized domains with non-ASCII characters, though.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with this site's formatting. As such, some characters are missing within, which is why I assume point you to a source that will have the answers, unscathed. @GCATNM: very true, but I don't think (though I may be wrong) they are looking to be _that_ all-inclusive.

Comment: SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical

Answer (score 2):

PHP already has a way to validate URLs, [`filter_var`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), which will work better than your regex (which as I commented above, allows false positives):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/example(200)aaaa.rar";
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the specification will answer your question [RFC-2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#page-19), though you will need to unpack your BNF boots for the journey.

In summary, pretty much any character can be used after the the domain name, excepting the few reserved ones which must be escaped:

> The BNF [in the RFC] includes national characters not allowed in valid URLs as specified by RFC 1738, since HTTP servers are not restricted in the set of unreserved characters allowed to represent the rel_path part of addresses, and HTTP proxies may receive requests for URIs not defined by RFC 1738