# Need a regex that matches URLs with/without http:// or www. or http://www. in a text

Tags: php, regex, url

I've been trying to find a solution myself but I couldnt do it so far (even tried all regexlib.com suggestions), so:

Need a regex that matches URLs like (PHP code):

http://example.com orhttp://www.example.com or
www.example.com 
example.com

---

I've been trying to use this one (catch http://(optional)www.example.com/path/otherpath):

$regex = "/(((ftp|https?)://www.)|(www.)|(http://))([\d\w-.]+?)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/,=]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/";

but it's not enough.

Still missing the example.com. Any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest searching google and StackOverflow. This is a very broad and complex topic which has been discussed several times.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you want to do - match *only* urls that include either the `http://` and (optionally?) the `www.`, or are you just looking to match all valid urls? (i.e. `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, `http://stackoverflow.com`, `www.stackoverflow.com`, and `stackoverflow.com`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```cs
(www|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([\.[:alnum:]_-]){0,4}([[:alnum:]_-]+\.)([[:alnum:]_-]\.?)([[:alpha:]]){0,3}
```