# a quick question about url validation

Tags: php, validation

I don't really want to use curl or anything complex like that.
I was looking for a simple way to check if the url (User will enter the url and it is then stored in my MySQL database) is valid and that it is a valid url i.e. the domain exists.
Is fopen a good solution?

Any tutorials or tips on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CURL isn't that complex. To get the http status of a url:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($status >= 200 && $status < 400) {
    // url is valid
}
```

A regex or filter would validate that the url is valid but not that it exists. A DNS lookup validates that the domain exists, but not the url.

Comment: thanks for the reply, do i need any specific framework (like are more files needed to make the above code work)?

Comment: You will need cURL support enabled in you PHP setup. You can check this by creating a PHP file containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then visit that page in your browser.

Comment: CURL is installed on pretty much every php environment I've ever seen, although I know what they say about assumption...

Comment: owh right, i'm using XAMMP for windows (migrating to using the mac version soon though) I tried CURL before and it said I had a "Fatal error: call to and undefined function" or something like that?  I'll try the phpinfo thing now

Comment: I have now though. Can Curl do like validation (Check if its http:) etc>??

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm using MAMP on Mac and it comes with CURL installed.

Comment: I had to chnage the php.ini file, its been sorted now, curl is active.

Comment: Can I use cURL to check the url is actually in the url format before we check it with the cURL code you've provided?

Comment: just seen your regex note on your comment

Comment: i'm using: if(preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url)){ //url is valid }else{ //url is not valid }. However: www.google.com seems to be considered invalid by my preg_match statement :/

Comment: `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` will return true if `$url` is a valid url format

Comment: thank you.  When i enter a valid url, it display my headers in the div and say the document has moved to the specified url?

Answer (score 2):

First, validate that it is a valid URL using [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var):

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.example.com/foo.php";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
  die('Invalid URL');
}
```

Next, parse the URL with [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and ensure that it is HTTP(S):

```
$p_url = parse_url($url);
if(!$p_url) // couldn't parse URL, since parse_url() cannot recognize it
{
  die('Invalid URL');
}
if($p_url['scheme'] != 'http' && $p_url['scheme'] != 'https')
{
  die('Invalid protocol (only HTTP(S) is supported)');
}
```

Lastly, check that the host exists and that you can connect to it. I choose to use [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/fsockopen) here, since it would check the hostname and port, while not actually sending an HTTP request.

```
$fp = fsockopen($p_url['host'], (isset($p_url['port']) ? $p_url['port'] : 80));
if($fp)
{
  echo 'Valid URL';
  fclose($fp); // Remember to close the file pointer
}else{
  echo 'Invalid server';
}
```

Note that you might want to avoid using this method (depending on what you want your application to do), as if the server is down, this would result in `Invalid server`, even though the server might exist. An alternative solution that will only check the hostname from the DNS servers, and not connect at all, is using [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr) and [`gethostbyname()`](http://php.net/gethostbyname):

```
if(@gethostbyaddr($p_url['host'])) // IP addresses passes this test
{
  echo 'Valid URL';
}else{
  $host = $p_url['host'];
  $addr = gethostbyname($host);
  if(!$addr) // Invalid domain name
  {
    echo 'Invalid domain name';
  }else if($host == $addr) // Domain name could not be resolved (i.e. does not exist)
  {
    echo 'Invalid domain name';
  }else{
    echo 'Valid URL';
  }
}
```

Links:

- [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) - Validate strings
- [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) - Parses URLs into arrays
- [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/fsockopen) - Opens a socket connection
- [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr) - Gets the domain name of an IP address (not sure if it supports IPv6, though)
- [`gethostbyname()`](http://php.net/gethostbyname) - Gets the IPv4 address of a domain name

Answer (score 0):

You should try filter_var

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
  echo "URL is not valid";
}
else
{
  echo "URL is valid";
}
?>
```

Read the [filter_var manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: This won't check that the URL actually exists, only that it is valid.

Comment: ah "the url is valid and that it is actually a url" is a little confusing as something like `http://blahblahblah.com` is actually an url. There just isn't a site for it :-)

Comment: sorry, i'll ammend the original question, sorry, was a bit vague there

Comment: @Callum - no problem. I'll leave this answer up but I agree that [adam's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700560/a-quick-question-about-url-validation/3700625#3700625) looks like what you need.