# Regex for url validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Hi,

in my form I have a url field. The user my input all kind of web url's. I use the following regex to validate the url:

```
/^(https?):\/\/(?:[A-Z0-9-]+.)+[A-Z]{2,6}([\/?].+)?$/i
```

But this regex handles some url's as invalid, e.g. the following

*http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.asp?ref=537448&site=5643&type=b479&bnb=479*

Any ideas how to improve the regex?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Comment: -1 for being lazy. The first answer StackOverflow suggested when entering "Regex for url validation" as question title answers your question. Please do not litter StackOverflow with duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
filter_var('example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
```

do not use regular expressions where is's not necessary

Comment: what is this feature, never heard of it. I want to use regex because I am working with zend framework and I am not sure how to apply this

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Note that `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` has some flaws and manual validation might still be necessary (at least this is what I heard).

Comment: This will allow invalid URLs like `http://??/` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved many times before. See [here](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls), for example.

Answer (score 1):

As for your regex, the first period needs to be escaped like this

```
/^(https?):\/\/(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}([\/?].+)?$/i
```