# asp.net allow german characters in Url

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-validation

I am using `RegularExpressionValidator` control with

```
[http(s)?://]*([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?
```

regular expression to validate Url. I need to allow german characters

> (ä,Ä,É,é,ö,Ö,ü,Ü,ß)

in Url. What should be exact regular expression to allow these characters?

Comment: Being native German, I never heard of a German character `É` or `é`. Actually, I heard of them in the French class in school.

Comment: @Uwe Keim Thank you for point this out. Do you know, which german characters are allowed in domain names?

Comment: If it is an "[Umlaut Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)" there should be all of those you named allowed (except those `É` and `é`). In addition there is also a rather new character which is the upper-case version of `ß`. (See [this German Wikipedia section](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Gro.C3.9Fschreibweise_mit_Versal-Eszett) about the upper-case character)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are aware that it is not easy to use regex for URL validation, because there are many valid variations of URLs. See for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).

First your regex has several flaws (this is only after a quick check, maybe not complete)

See [here for online check on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tn6a)

It does not match

> [http://RegExr.com?2rjl6]](http://RegExr.com?2rjl6%5D)

Why do you allow only `\w` and `-` after the first dot?

but it does match

> hhhhhhppth??????ht://stackoverflow.com

You define a character group at the beginning `[http(s)?://]` what means match any of the characters inside (You probaly want `(?:http(s)?://)` and `?` after wards instead of `*`.

To answer your question:

Create a character group with those letters and put it where you want to allow it.

```
[äÄÉéöÖüÜß]
```

Use it like this

```
(?:https?://)?([äÄÉéöÖüÜß\w-]+\.)+[äÄÉéöÖüÜß\w-]+(/[-äÄÉéöÖüÜß\w ./?%&amp;=]*)?
```

Other hints

The `-` inside of a character group has to be at the start or the end or needs to be escaped.

`(s)?` is `s?`

Comment: Excellent. My original issue is resolved. I changed regex to (?:http(s)?://)?([äÄÉéöÖüÜß\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)? and it is now allowing german characters and also does not allow hhhhhhppth??????ht://stackoverflow.com. But, you have pointed out a very important thing that it does not match http://RegExr.com?2rjl6] (query string) which is very normal. What changes I need to make in my above regex to allow querystring?

Comment: As I said in my first sentence, its not trivial and has already been discussed a several times here (I provided there also a link with a solution). A quick answer is: add the `?` to the character class, but I am sure then there are other valid URLs that will not be matched, maybe a better link is this [stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url). Look at the solutions there and add your additional characters.