# help with a regex code

Tags: php, regex, url

i have this regex code

```
/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i
```

it works but there is a problem
you NEED http:// in the url for it to validate, and what i am making, the user will not want to add http:// to the url they want to just have example.com, if its possible i need it to work weather it has http:// or not
i don't know how to make my own regex, and ive searched but cannot find a one that does what i need, unless im just not looking in the right place. (Google :P)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP validation/regex for URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother with regex. Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make it optional

```
/^((?:https?:\/\/+)?[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i
```

The `(?:)` around the part you don't want to have is a non capturing group, the `?` afterwards makes it optional.

I'm not sure what the `+` after the second slash is good for, it says at least one of the preceding character. That means it allows also stuff like `http://////////`.

I hope you are aware, that this regex is far from matching valid URLs.

For example it will match stuff like

```
http://////////------------.-
```

or at least

```
http://N.O
          ^ after this position you can write what you want and it will match valid.
```

[Here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u1ul) you can see what your regex is matching.

See Purple Coder's answer for a probably better solution.

Answer (score 0):

/^((https?:\/\/+)?[\w-]+.[\w-]+)/i

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this :

// Validate that the string contains at least a dot .

```
var filterWebsite =  /^([a-zA-Z0-9:_\.\-/])+\.([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-/])+$/;
```