# Yii: How can I linkify all URLs in some text?

Tags: php, yii

Say I have a forum thread and I want to make all mentioned URLs as clickable links. How can I accomplish this in Yii?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look into [CHtmlPurifier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtmlPurifier)? see: [Linkify](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#AutoFormat.Linkify) and http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php

Answer (score 3):

This is copied straight from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

```
$text = preg_replace("
  #((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie",
  "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4'",
  $text
);
```