# Parsing a valid url in php

Tags: php, regex, url

I have this regex to filter out urls but its also filtering out some invalid urls

```
    $regexUrl = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME 
    $regexUrl .= "([a-zA-Z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass 
    $regexUrl .= "([a-zA-Z0-9-.]*)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP 
    $regexUrl .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port 
    $regexUrl .= "(\/([a-zA-Z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path 
    $regexUrl .= "(\?[a-zA-Z+&\$_.-][a-zA-Z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query 
    $regexUrl .= "(#[a-zA-Z_.-][a-zA-Z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor
```

for instance "http://...XYZ" is also filtered by the above regex but this is invalid url.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is a valid URL for you? Can you specify this a bit more? Which protocols are valid for you? which server names? Which ports? Does the path matter? Should authorization work or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP validation/regex for URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Comment: Why is http://...XYZ an invalid url? Not all domains start with `www` and end in `.com`. For example, `localhost` is a valid domain as much as www.xyz.com. So are `the`, `duplicate` and `question`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Host or IP line, change `*` to `+` and remove the `.` from the first `[]`

```
$regexUrl .= "([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP
```

The effect of this is to require (with +) some characters from the first `[]` and not permit a `.` among them since the `.` is handled (and required) by the `\.` which follows the first group.

Answer (score 3):

```
$valid = parse_url($url);
```

is it what are you looking for?

Comment: no I am looking for something like "This is a great website visit www.xyz.com" now I need to filter out this "www.xyz.com" from the message, but the above regex is not filtering invalid ones "as shown in the question"

Comment: As far as the LOL is concerned, the function is called `parse_url` infact and BTW, the real LOL is here when you give the example a run on the example URL: http://codepad.org/mbiMPUuu

Comment: From the docs: _This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly._

Comment: @Michael: I know it isn't... but you would have to make CURL or other network call to get if URL is valid

Comment: @genesis "validate" in this context doesn't mean the URL maps to a valid host, but that the pattern is valid.  `parse_url()` will dutifully parse the incorrect URL "http://...XYZ" as `[scheme] => http [host] => ...XYZ`

Comment: Is `...XYZ` an invalid hostname? Actually I had no problem to make it work with my name resolution, ping just loves it!

Comment: It is not really possible to autodetect bare hostnames like www.xyz.com without the http schema prefix. Every word in this comment is also a perfectly valid hostname. IDN makes almost anything non-ASCII a potential hostname. Hostnames need not begin with www-dot and there are increasingly too many TLDs to make it practical to use that as a signifier.