# PHP Url Validation Error: http://https://example.com (aka https://https://example.com)

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

I had this url regex pattern in place:

```
$pattern = "@\b(https?://[^\s()<>\[\]\{\}]{1,".$max_length_allowed_for_each_url."}(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))@";
```

It seemed to work pretty well at validating any URL I threw at it, until I realized that https://http://google.com (apparently even stackoverflow is considering that a valid URL (it made that URL clickable, not me, although it did remove one of the colons) so perhaps I am out of luck?) was a valid URL, when it certainly is not.

I did a little research... and learnt that I [should be using filter_var instead of a regex for PHP URL validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/207627/226001) anyways... and was disappointed to realize that it too is susceptible to this very same validation problem.

I could easily conquer it with:

```
str_replace(array("https://http://","http://https://"), array("http://","https://"), $url);
```

But... that just seems so wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is a valid URI.  Technically.  Look at the RFC for URIs if you don't believe me.

- The path component of a URI can contain `//`.
- `http` is a valid host name.
- The port is allowed to be missing even if the `:` is present (it's specified as `*digit`, not `1*digit`).  (This is why Stack Overflow removed the colon -- it thought you were using the default port, so it removed it from the URI.)

I suggest writing a special case for this.  In a separate step, check to see if the URI starts with `https?://https?://`, and fix it.