# Validating URL with and without protocol with filter_var

Tags: php, validation

I am attempting to validate using PHP's `filter_var()` extension.  Per http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php:

> Validates value as URL (according to »
>   http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396), optionally with required
>   components. Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol
>   http:// so further validation may be required to determine the URL
>   uses an expected protocol, e.g. ssh:// or mailto:. Note that the
>   function will only find ASCII URLs to be valid; internationalized
>   domain names (containing non-ASCII characters) will fail.

In regards to, **Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol**, my tests below indicate that a HTTP protocol is required (`URL 'stackoverflow.com/' is NOT considered valid.`).  How am I misinterpreting the documentation?

Also, how are URLs such as https://https://stackoverflow.com/ prevented from validating true?

PS.  Any comments on my approach of sanitizing the protocol would be appreciated.

```
<?php
function filterURL($url) {
    echo("URL '{$url}' is ".(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)?'':' NOT ').'considered valid.<br>');
}
function sanitizeURL($url) {
    return (strtolower(substr($url,0,7))=='http://' || strtolower(substr($url,0,8))=='https://')?$url:'http://'.$url;
}

filterURL('http://stackoverflow.com/');
filterURL('https://stackoverflow.com/');
filterURL('//stackoverflow.com/');
filterURL('stackoverflow.com/');
filterURL(sanitizeURL('http://stackoverflow.com/'));
filterURL(sanitizeURL('https://stackoverflow.com/'));
filterURL(sanitizeURL('stackoverflow.com/'));

filterURL('https://https://stackoverflow.com/');
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
URL 'http://stackoverflow.com/' is considered valid.
URL 'https://stackoverflow.com/' is considered valid.
URL '//stackoverflow.com/' is NOT considered valid.
URL 'stackoverflow.com/' is NOT considered valid.
URL 'http://stackoverflow.com/' is considered valid.
URL 'https://stackoverflow.com/' is considered valid.
URL 'http://stackoverflow.com/' is considered valid.
URL 'https://https://stackoverflow.com/' is considered valid.
```

Comment: The last one causes some concern: `https://https://stackoverflow.com/`. Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: [Eval.in:  PHP — PHP 5.5.14, pasted just now](https://eval.in/private/c0fba9b3d8befb). Not what is expected.

Comment: Valid URL may specify any protocol **other** than HTTP, but protocol is still mandatory.

Comment: `https://https://stackoverflow.com` sadly is a valid url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238498/php-url-validation-error-http-https-example-com-aka-https-https-exampl The suggestions made in this answer is to add a custom check to invalidate these cases.

Comment: @`stackoverflow.com` not validating: You could use http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php to check if the URL in question contains a protocol and if it doesn't prepend "http://" before further validation.

Answer (score 4):

`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` uses `parse_url()`, which unfortunatelly parses `'https://https://'` as a valid URL (as it is really a valid one considering URIs RFC):

```
var_dump(parse_url('https://https://stackoverflow.com/'));

array(3) { 
  ["scheme"]=> string(5) "https" 
  ["host"]=> string(5) "https"
  ["path"]=> string(20) "//stackoverflow.com/" 
}
```

You could change your `sanitazeURL` function into:

```
function sanitizeURL($url) {
  return (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME)) ? $url : 'http://' . $url;
}
```

but still you have to check whether host name is not `http` nor `https`:

```
function filterURL($url) {
  echo("URL '{$url}' is ".((filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false && (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) !== 'http' && parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) !== 'https'))?'':' NOT ').'considered valid.<br>');
}
```

Comment: @"use proper Regular Expression" Beware that `https://https://stackoverflow.com/`is indeed a valid URL. The `:` after the host name is used for the port and the path may contain `//`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the http or add it by validation it exist or not.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.nigeriatest.com";

// Remove all illegal characters from a url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

// Validate url
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

Comment: Then even `WhAtEvErhttp://www.nigeriatest.com` is a valid URL, because `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` flag simply doesn't care about protocol validation... Besides, what's the point of removing illegal characters when we want to test whether it is valid or not? If it contains illegal characters then it is invalid for sure...

Answer (score 0):

My idea of solving this issue is to remove the existing protocol and force add one.

```
        $value = str_replace(['http://', 'https://'], '', $value);
        $value = filter_var("https://$value", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Answer (score -1):

> How am I misinterpreting the documentation?

The specification doesn't say anything about not having a protocol - it simply states that the protocol might not be HTTP.

You chop of the important piece of the sentence in your quote...

> Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol http:// **so
>   further validation may be required to determine the URL uses an
>   expected protocol**

A protocol is **expected**, it *may or may not* be HTTP.

Comment: You may be technically correct, but at best this is incredibly misleading documentation.  Why would someone expect scheme to be required when there is a flag to require scheme (that apparently does nothing) FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED. 
 This may not be an implementation bug, but it's definitely a documentation bug.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240033/what-is-use-of-filter-flag-scheme-required-and-filter-flag-host-required-flags-f/45240693

Comment: @DougW - The question was "How am I misinterpreting the documentation?" - and the answer is clear, because you aren't reading it all. The flags you mention have not had any effect since 5.2.1

Comment: I read it all.  The phrase "may not specify the HTTP protocol" is not clear.  It could mean "you are not allowed to specify http", or "http (and perhaps all schemes) can be omitted".  In the second case, the documentation is not clear about what is meant--can http simply be implied for URIs without a scheme (as is common practice)?  Or is a scheme required, just not necessarily http?  The imprecision of the language used makes the documentation unclear.

Comment: To be clear, a user would have to find this note in the version change log, and realize that it means that the inverse (no scheme required) is now impossible since flags can't be un-set.  Feel free to disagree, but IMO documentation that is incorrect without scrutinizing historical change logs is bad documentation.

`5.2.1 FILTER_VALIDATE_URL now implicitly uses FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED and FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED.`

Comment: @DougW - it is clear, "may not" isn't the same as "must not" so reading it as "you are not allowed to specify http" would be at best bizarre. It means, quite clearly, that the protocol may or may not be HTTP. FWIW It isn't just the docs, PHP is garbage and full of inconsistencies - but that doc is pretty clear unless you are going out of your way to misconstrue it.