# Regex URL Match

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I just really started learning how to use regex's and i am trying to create one to match urls. So far i have:

```
(http://|https://|www|\w)+\.[\w]{2,4}[^\s]+
```

can anyone give me some feedback or advice on how this looks, or maybe point me in a better

Comment: do you have a specific question?

Comment: Honestly I would look online for a good one.  URLs aren't incredibly complex, but there's always some fringe case you wouldn't think of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: well i am just learning regex's and want to know if this is legit, it checks out, but will grab a few extra characters, can anyone make any modifications to this to make it better?

Comment: This question has been asked so many times. See the related questions part of the page on the bottom right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex you wrote is a good start, the true power of regex is that it can be very... well... powerful :)
there are a lot of differences in the structure of URL that are still considered ok.

consult a [Regex Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) to learn more and understand the meaning of all the characters.

and you can check for what the community generates by going to a site like [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

this may be overly complex for what you need but this is a well written regex for URLmatching: `^(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$`

> on a side note i use this online [Regex Helper](http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html) to test my regex strings without the need to actually run them from the code.

Comment: yeah, i have been using gskinner.com/regexr , thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try: `^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$` Note that depending on how you are using it, you might want to remove the ^ and $ from the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of stuff on the web...

- You can look at what we do within [Horde](http://www.horde.org): [Horde URL filter](https://github.com/horde/horde/blob/master/framework/Text_Filter/lib/Horde/Text/Filter/Linkurls.php)
- Ours has been derived from http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
- And there is also [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)