# Making links clickable from comments in php

Tags: php, hyperlink, chat, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex URL Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164839/regex-url-match)

im trying to create functions that will give my chat clickable links.... here are the functions i've created

```
<?php
//makes links starting with http clickable
    function makehttpclickable($text){
        return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp://)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
//makes links starting www. http clickable

function clickywww($www){
    return preg_replace('!((www)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $www);
}
/function that gives me an error!
function clickydotcom($noob){
    return preg_replace('!([-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)(\.com)!i'.'!([-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)(\.com)!f', '<a href="$1.com$f">$1.com</a>', $noob);
}
```

I've been getting an unkown modifier error. 
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '!' 
So Anyways any help would be nice on how i can make all types of links clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do it

```
 <?php
 $input= "website is http://www.xyz.com";
 $clickable = preg_replace('*(f|ht)tps?://[A-Za-z0-9\./?=\+&%]+*', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $input);
 echo $clickable;
 ?>
```

I have made some modification according to above solution in your function. This code will make ftp, http, etc links clickable

```
 <?php
 function makehttpclickable($input){
 return preg_replace('*(f|ht)tps?://[A-Za-z0-9\./?=\+&%]+*', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $input);
 }
 ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `ereg_replace` function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php