# Regex Match URL/Domain/Filename For IIS10

Tags: c#, regex, url-rewriting, iis-10

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164839/regex-url-match) link but it doesn't cover my requirements.

I am looking to create a regex for IIS10 that matches certain critea and if it doesn't then do something with the URL Rewrite like redirect to the home page.

My attempt at this rule:

```
(https?:\/\/example\.com).*?(\/)?([Dd]?efault\.aspx)?
```

I would like for it to be able to check against the following URL's:

Good URL's:

```
https://example.com/default.aspx
https://example.com
```

Bad URL's:

```
http://example.com/default.aspx
http://example.com/directory/somepagename.aspx
http://example.com/ 
http://example.com 
http://example.com/ADirectory/default.aspx
http://www.example.com/default.aspx
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/default.aspx
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com
```

So, any URL which is HTTP is rejected. Any URL with HTTPS which matches one of the two GOOD URL's is fine. Any HTTPS url that has a sub-directory is a BAD URL. Any URL that has WWW in the domain name should be rejected (including HTTPS). Match Case = No (Case Insensitive).

Maybe in a few months, I will replace the IIS10 rule and use it in a C# handler.

Much Appreciated

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Check out mistake 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make the `s?` optional if you don't want to match only http. Instead of using `.*?` which can match a `/`, you can use a negated character class matching any char except the forward slash `[^/]*` not allowing a subfolder

If you don't want to allow a trailing slash, you can include it in the last optional group, and if you want to match the whole string you can use anchors `^` and `$`

```
^(https://example\.com)[^/]*(/?[Dd]?efault\.aspx)?$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZTMCQ/1/)