# extracting links as clickable links from sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Been at this for a while and cant figure it out so i thought id come to the ppl who know.
my php / sql is so-so but.....this is what im trying to do / figure out..

i have a database setup to take in messages (of any sort) and works fine. The user enters data in a field, hits send, and the message gets logged.

But when a user puts in a link for example `" http://www.google.com "`
its stored in the DB just fine but when its printed back onto the page, it comes back as plain
text, what i want is that when the page throws back the message with the link in it, that the link is live and clickable.

Ive googled my a$# off but im guessing im searching for the wrong thing (or im missing something unbeknownst to me. )

Any **tips**/**direction** etc, ill gladly accept. also, I dont mind doing the work/research so if you have links only ill take those too.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Of course, you must construct an html link in order to have a clickable link...You need to recognize the link and surround it with the right html markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse messages plain text in order to find links. Then, change link texts by adding an anchor tag (`<a>`).

[This link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/) should help you.

Comment: thanks that got it working. On that link, the example kept throwing errors, turns out the problem was a quoting problem...double quotes within another set of double quotes. i just changed the inner pair to single and works 100%. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

you need regular expressions to detect links and convert them to `<a href="$link">...</a>`
see the answer here:

[PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php for replacing regular expressions with something.

There you want to replace every website with a typical html link syntax like `<a href="...">...</a>`

Comment: Note that "<a>" alone isn't valid, you need to indicate the href attribute too

Comment: yes I know that:D That was the short answer. I assumed he knows that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo "your_field"; ?>"> <?php echo "your_field"; ?> </a>
```

Comment: The OP said *messages (of any sort)* so I guess there is not a field which contains only the link. Links are mixed up with plain text.

Comment: @S0pra in the above question, its stated that (when a user puts in a link for example " http://www.google.com " its stored in the DB just fine ) i m talking about that LINK_FIELD :-p

Comment: yeah thats what i mean S0pra. i have say a paragraph and in that paragraph of text, a link somewhere in there, i need a way to parse that on print into a clickable link.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (I took this from some code I wrote for a client):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wcordersinfo WHERE dealer_id = '" . $dealer_id . "' && drawing_num = " . $_GET['reference_id'] . "");
    while ($orders = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        if ($orders['drawing_num'] != '') {
            $link_open = '<a href="http://www.example.com/dealers/order-details.php?reference_id=' . $orders['drawing_num'] . '">';
            $link_close = '</a>';
        } else {
            $link_open = $link_close = '';
        }
```

and then where you want to display the content:

```
<?php echo "<li>' . $link_start . $orders['carrier'] . $link_end . '</li>"; ?>
```