# Struggling to use a regex function to find a link in a string

Tags: php, regex, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to extract a string from another string using php.

At the moment im using:

```
<?php
  $testVal = $node->field_link[0]['view'];
  $testVal = preg_replace("#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie", "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4'", $testVal);
  print "testVal = ";
  print $testVal;
?>
```

This seems to be printing my entire string at the moment.

Now what i want to do is: extract a web address if there is one and save it as a variable called testVal.

I am a novice so please explain what i am doing wrong. Also i have looked at other questions and have used the regex from one.

For @bos

Input:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CLXt3yh2g0s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Desired Output

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/CLXt3yh2g0s
```

Comment: You write that you want to find a link, but your regexp hints that you want to find an URL and turn it into a link. Which is it?

Comment: I want to find a url and save it as a variable. It may be that the regex is wrong :/

Comment: Show test cases. Show indata, actual outdata and expected outdata.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you say you want to populate `$testVal` with the extracted web address, but you're using `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`. You use `preg_replace` when you wish to *replace* occurrences, and you use `preg_match` (or `preg_match_all`) when you want to *find* occurrences.

If you want to replace URLs with links (`<a>` tags) like in your example, use something like this:

```
<?php
$testVal = preg_replace(
     '/((?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|irc:\/\/)[^\s<>()"]+?(?:\([^\s<>()"]*?\)[^\s<>()"]*?)*)((?:\s|<|>|"|\.||\]|!|\?|,|&#44;|&quot;)*(?:[\s<>()"]|$))/',
     '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="$1">$1</a>$2',
     $testVal
);
```

If you want to instead simply locate a URL from a string, try (using your regex now instead of mine above):

```
<?php
$testVal = $node->field_link[0]['view'];
if(!preg_match("#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie", $testVal, $matches)) {
     echo "Not found!";
else {
     echo "URL: " . $matches[1];
}
```

When you use `preg_match`, the (optional) third parameter is filled with the results of the search. `$matches[0]` would contain the string that matched the entire pattern, `$matches[1]` would contain the first capture group, `$matches[2]` the second, and so on.