# Match all URLs exclude jpg,gif,png

Tags: java, php, regex, match, imageurl

I want to match all URLS but exclude image urls from beeing matched with that regex: jpe?g|gif|png .

\b(?:https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$

The problem is that the part with the exclude is not working like this: (?!jpe?g|gif|png)

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Example:

not Matchen:

```
http://example.com/example.jpg
http://example.com/example231/example.gif
```

Match:

```
http://example.com/example.html
http://example.com/example/?id=4331
http://example.com/example/example/ex_ample/ex-ample/?id=4331
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start your regex with `(?!.*(?:\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.png)$)`,

so if your current regex is `\b(?:https?|ftp|file)://...`, then merge it to

`(?!.*(?:\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.png)$)\b(?:https?|ftp|file)://...`

Read also [PHP URL validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435452/php-url-validation)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this problem for a recent duplicate question that got closed, so I'll post it here:

`((?!.*(png|jpg|gif)(?!.))(?:https?|file|ftp):\/\/.*.\.(?:com|ca|net|museum|org|co\.uk))`

Feel free to add more protocals if appropriate, more image extensions if appropriate, and more top level domains if appropriate.

[Tested on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aB6jD5)