# How to add target="_blank" on the existing <a href=""> </a>?

Tags: php, html, tags

I have a variable that contains the following text in PhP:

```
$description = "Flash <a href=\"http://www.aaa.com/\">this coupon</a> <br > <a href="http://www.ggg.com/">Visit here</a> for details <br >";
```

How do i add the

> target="_blank"

that missing on the `$description` variable?

**So the result will becomes the following:**

```
$description = "Flash <a href=\"http://www.aaa.com/\" target="_blank">this coupon</a> <br > <a href="http://www.ggg.com/" target="_blank">Visit here</a> for details <br >";
```

I am looking for solution that the variable $description was recorded by user accidentally. But I need the system to find out and correct it by adding the target="blank" into the existing variable and update the record.

Comment: What is your question? Why can't you do it exactly as you've outlined here?

Comment: You can do it exactly as you said, but you should escape your quotes (even in your first example) or maybe consider wrapping it in single quotes and use double quotes for the HTML properties.

Comment: single quota inside single quota should be escaped with \, also same for double quota, you can use single quota inside double quota without any escape and vice versa

Comment: I think the question is about HOW, not knowing the URL of the `<a>` he can inject the `target="_blank"`

Comment: I am looking for solution that the variable $description was recorded by user accidentally. But I need the system to find out and correct it by adding the target="blank" into the existing variable and update the  record.

Comment: That is more complicated since you need to check if the link already has this attribute, you could to this with a regular expression e.g.

Comment: @user1109161 Take a look @ my post. I edited my answer. $string = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)>/", "<a$1 target=\"_blank\">", $string);

Answer (score 20):

I have no idea what your exactly meaning. However, a suggestion to use ' within your HTML. And only " for the echo.
So it will be:

```
$description = "Flash <a href='http://www.aaa.com/' target='_blank'>this coupon</a><br ><a href='http://www.ggg.com/' target='_blank'>Visit here</a> for details <br >";
```

For adding target you can use this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)>/", "<a$1 target=\"_blank\">", $string);
```

Found on: [preg_replace links in text with <a> with some exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845369/preg-replace-links-in-text-with-a-with-some-exception)

Comment: You should do it the other way around. `'` for the string and `"` for the html attributes. Although single quotes are allowed, double quotes are a bit more the "standard" way for html.

Answer (score 3):

```
$description = str_replace('<a href="','<a target="_blank" href="',$description);
```

Comment: This wont work if there are other tags used first, like `<a type='image' href='...'></a>`

Answer (score 2):

You already did it, but your code will produce errors since you didn't escape the `"` in the second link

```
$description = "Flash <a href=\"http://www.aaa.com/\" target=\"_blank\">this coupon</a> <br > <a href=\"http://www.ggg.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Visit here</a> for details <br >";
```

Alternatively you can use `'` then you don't have to escape

```
$description = 'Flash <a href="http://www.aaa.com/" target="_blank">this coupon</a> <br > <a href="http://www.ggg.com/" target="_blank">Visit here</a> for details <br >';
```

Comment: Sorry guys, maybe I have mislead my question. Have just updated the question again.

Answer (score 1):

If you note that properties of tags do not have a specific order, you can simply replace `<a href` with `<a target=\"_blank\" href`

Comment: hi @hexblot, thanks for the comment. Actually, I am looking for solution that the variable $description was recorded by user accidentally. But I need the system to find out and correct it by adding the target="blank" into the existing variable and update the record