# Test for URL Format

Tags: url, validation

I'd like to test whether the URL that the user inputs into my form is "proper", e.g. the following are proper:

```
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com/
```

but the following probably shouldn't be:

```
google
http://www.go?ogle?#%
```

I don't have in mind what "proper" means, but is there some standard out there that I can use?

Comment: Wikipedia would be better than Google for something like this. So check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: Okay, that looks like a good resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5 you can use the `input` element with the `type` value `url`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#url-state-type-url. You'd need to check which browsers already implemented a validation for it, though. If it's important, you'd also need server-side validation, of course.

Here you can see what URLs are considered valid by HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/urls.html#valid-url. It references [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for URIs and [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) for IRIs.

You should probably have a look at RegEx for URL validation (see for example this question: [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206059/1591669)) or check if your library/programming-language/CMS has special functions for it.