# Check if there's an URL between span tags

Tags: php, regex, string

I got a HTML code containing following:

```
<span rel="url">example.com</span>
<span rel="url">example.net.pl [SOMETHING]</span>
<span rel="url">[SOMETHING]imjustanexample.com</span> [..]
```

The question is, if there is a way to get the "url" string from between `span` tags. eg. it should  get the following: `example.com`, `example.net.pl` (without the `[SOMETHING]` string), and `imjustanexample.com`.

I guess I will have to use regex for this purpose.

Comment: You will need to give more concrete examples I'm afraid, because your strings so far don't contain any url's.

Comment: You're right, it doesnt I meant those `example.com` ones..

Comment: Let me put it another way, what can `[something]` be? And `example.com` is NOT a url! A url is `http://example.com/`.

Comment: @Jack I know! `[something]` is can be any string - not really with the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression in javascript,

```
/((http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)|)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
```

to validate text from span tag

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way (either in regex or just PHP code, like you prefer):

1. Locate next ""
2. Take everything from it's end until the next (but not including) space  or lower-than sign `<` (whichever of those tow comes first).
3. Repeat until nothing is matched any longer.

Done. If regular expression is too complicated for you, you can also take string functions http://php.net/strings .

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work:

```
$str = '<span rel="url">http://google.ca</span>';
$match = preg_match('#<span(.*)?>((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|"|\'|:|\<|$|\.\s)</span>#i', $str, $matches);
if($match)
    var_dump($matches);
else
    echo 'Nope<br />';
```

Regex from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/206087/1533203

Answer (score -1):

Check out Simple HTML Dom Parser ( [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) ).

With it you can simply access elements on the DOM tree.

Your problem could be solved with:

```
  $html->find("span[rel=url]");
```

And then you could simply use a loop on all elements and some regex which fits your needs.