# Regex link-like match without last puntuaction character

Tags: php, regex

I have html/text string and want to match all links-like parts of the text to real hyperlinks with A tag. For this question I'am trying to match "www.somesite.domen" pattern. But, what if the pattern is near punctuation character at the end of the sentence.

**How to match pattern without very last character which is punctuation?**

1. www.somesite.domen.
2. www.somesite.domen,
3. www.somesite.domen?
4. www.somesite.domen!
5. www.somesite.domen/?id=1?

Here is the function I'am using for:

```
function make_links($text)
{
  return  preg_replace(
     array(
        '/(^|\s)(www\.[^<>\s!,]+)(!$|\s|\.|\:|\!|,|\?)/iex'
       ),
     array(
        "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a>\\3':'\\0'))"
       ),
       $text
   );
}
```

But when the '.' or '?' characters are the last in sentence, my function is taking them into the link too.

Any idea how to solve this cases? Thanks!

Comment: Does your text contain the `[]` to delimit the domain?

Comment: My text does not contain `[ ]`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you need to break your line of text into 3 groups

- The first group will keep text before *host name*
- The second group will keep the *host name*
- The third group will last punctuation character (or whitespace character).

One of the solutions could be as follows:

```
/^(.*?)(www(?:.\w+)+(?:\/[^.\s]+?))(!$|\s|\.|\:|\!|,|\?)?$/
```

[image: Regexp explained]

Using `some text www.host.some-site.domen/?id=1?` as an example you would get matching as follows:

[image: Matching results]

In order to fiddle with your regexp you can use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/)

**EDIT**

Alternatively this is another regexp.

```
/^(.+\s)?(\w+(?:\.[-\w]+)+\.\w+(?:\/.*?)?)(!$|\s|\.|\:|\!|,|\?)?$/
```

I've performed several tests:

- Test text: `some stuff www.host.somesite.domen/?id=1.`. Matching groups:

  - 1: `some stuff`,
  - 2:`www.host.somesite.domen/?id=1`,
  - 3:`.`
- Test text: `some stuff www.host.somesite.domain.`. Matching groups:

  - 1:`some stuff`
  - 2:`www.host.somesite.domen`
  - 3:`.`
- Test text: `www.host.somesite.domain`. Matching groups (only one):

  - 2: `www.host.somesite.domain`
- Test text: `hello www.host.somesite.domen/mysite.`. Matching groups:

  - 1: `hello`,
  - 2:`www.host.somesite.domen/mysite`,
  - 3:`.`
- Test text: `www.somesite.domen/?id=1?`. Matching groups:

  - 2:`www.somesite.domen/?id=1`
  - 3:`?`

I hope that will help to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, the `[ ]` are not the part of the text. I have just removed them from the cases.

Comment: @Branislav, and what about host name, is it always www?

Comment: In this question link-like starts always with www.  so I have to match as more cases as I can BUT without punctuation at the end. Host name is welcome too. As you know the '.' and '?' can be in URL but not at the very end. Example: " This is my website URL www.hostname.com/mysite. "