# php Possible weaknesses for FILTER_VALIDATE_URL + fopen($url,"r") - url validation

Tags: php, filter, fopen, url-validation

my urls in my site'll have international characters such as `ş`, `ğ`, `ı` ...

after reading lots of posts and blogs for url validation issue, I decided to support `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` with another pieces of codes since

1. if url has int. characters, url can't validated
2. http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/why-url-validation-with-filter_var-might-not-be-a-good-idea/  answered by **bažmegakapa** with +7.

then I concluded to use this idea at [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

bažmegakapa offers to use

`if (preg_match("#^https?://.+#", $link) and @fopen($link,"r")) echo "OK";`

to see if link can be opened then it means it's validated.

After this point MY question:

**Question -** I loved this idea & it seems to me very brilliant. But after seeing that it has only +7 and that page has  +>>7 answers, I want to ask that what is the idea of php masters who will be glad to answer this question to help like the ones like me; the rookies.

Is there any weaknesses in bažmegakapa's code? for example I don't know but can there be any url that fopen can't open it but actually it's a harmless, must-be-validated url? So what is the cure of the weaknesses you detected?

thank you

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact, that `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` considers `javascript://test%0Aalert(321)` valid is not a weakness. If you think it is, your expectations about what `filter_var` is for are wrong.

`filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` validates the syntax of a URL against [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

- It is not meant to determine whether the resource pointed to by the URL is accesssible.
- It is not meant to determine whether it is safe to use the URL as the value of a `href` attribute in an `a` element of a HTML document when the URL is provided by a user.
- It is not meant to consider the scheme (which may place restrictions on URLs that go beyond what is described in [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)). For example while

  - `ftp://foo:bar@baz` is a valid FTP URL according to [RFC 1738, 3.2 FTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt),
  - `http://foo:bar@baz` is *not* a valid HTTP URL according to [RFC 2616, 3.2.2 http URL](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2) (even though some browsers can interpret such "URLs").

`filter_var` does not bake cakes, nor does it brew coffee. If you require cake or coffee, use something else ([RFC 2324](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324) is a good start).

Depending on the circumstances, displaying a URL wich points to a resource that your server cannot access might be a good idea or a bad idea. Depending on the circumstances, displaying a URL that does not point to HTTP or HTTPS resource might be a good idea or a bad idea. One size does not fit all.