# Validate a URL PHP

Tags: php, http, url

I've working on a project and in this project i need to check the user input is a valid URL.

I've made a preg_match for all possible characters used on a URL. However, I'm trying to make it show an error if HTTP:// / HTTPS:// is not in front of the URL.

Here is what I've done.

```
if(preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z.\-\/:?&=#%_]/', $url) || substr($url, 0, 7) != "http://" || substr($url, 0, 8) != "https://") {
```

But that doesn't work. It keeps giving me the an OK message. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I hope I can get some help!

The if statement will return true or false. So

```
    if(preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z.\-\/:?&=#%_]/', $url) || substr($url, 0, 7) != "http://" || substr($url, 0, 8) != "https://") {
echo "true";
} else {
echo "false";
}
```

I just need to check if the url has entered a valid url. I don't need to verify it. Just need to check if it has HTTP:// or HTTPS:// and contains valid URL characters.

Comment: Is this if being evaluated as true or false?  You didn't make it clear whether the if shows an OK message or an error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP validation/regex for URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Comment: please do not vandalize your own post.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of a regex, you could make things easy on yourself and use the URL filtering in [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { ...
```

Comment: On it own this does not answer the OP question, `filter_var('hxxpabc://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` is valid?

Comment: If `filter_var` produces a positive result you can inspect it with `parse_url`. This allows you to extract parts of the URL, like the scheme (http, https, hxxpabc).

Answer (score 7):

Alternately you can do this without regex. Though you do also need to validate the url imagine `http://">bla</a><script>alert('XSS');</script>` as the value passed as there url

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com';

if(in_array(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME),array('http','https'))){
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {
        //valid url
    }else{
        //not valid url
    }
}else{
    //no http or https
}
?>
```

- [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
- [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown your complete relevant code. So, not sure, why it is not working for you but for url validation, you can check for a detailed discussion on the thread link below:

[PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Answer (score 0):

To validate user input with website url it is good to allow with or without scheme and with or without www, then in view add scheme to set as external url.

```
    $withWww = 'www.' . str_replace(array('www.'), '', $value);
    $withScheme = 'http://' . str_replace(array('http://', 'htttps://'), '', $withWww);
    $headers = @get_headers($withScheme);
    if (strpos($headers[0], '200') === false) {
        return false;
    }
```