# How to remove only links from string and nothing more

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have string: Some text (some text) anylink.com www.anylink.com http://anylink.com R.I.O one-www.link.com

I have this code:

```
$pattern = "/[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+/i";
$replacement = "";
$name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $name);
```

It removes fine: anylink.com, www.anylink.com, http://anylink.com

But its also remove word R.I.O and one- how I can avoid this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: what makes the string "R.I.O" an invalid link? also, is this php?

Comment: Yes it is PHP. I want that word R.I.O would not be removed because its not link also one- should not be removed either.

Comment: but "one-www.link.com" could indeed be a valid URL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Comment: Yes you are right in that case lets forget one- just about R.I.O problem than.

Comment: do you want a regular expression to just work for that example string or do you want a regular expression to catch every possible URL?

Comment: Every possible URL would be perfect. But I can also write down all domain extensions by hand if needed.

Comment: then check the link i've sent you

Comment: That link is for links with html tag. My links don't have html tag they are like text.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should be sure of what is really a link or not
you need to find a pattern

I realize that all your links may end with .com
so try this regex `"[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+.com$"`

but if you need .com.anything or .com/anything

```
"[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+.com.*$"
```

Comment: I think this is more correct using your idea ([a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+)?[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9\/%&=\?\-_]+)+

Comment: PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '*' in /home/cg/root/main.php on line 10