# Regex Match Specific URL String

Tags: php, string

I have structure of URL like this: `https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=12a3456asdf789&token=12345Dasdew678`

The two parameters of the URL, `partner` and `token` will have dynamic values which can contain alphanumeric characters only.

I would like to know if the format of the URL meets my requirements

```
if($URLisFormattedProperly) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#refsect1-function.filter-var-examples

Comment: This question will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, regex based on your existing URL

```
preg_match('/https\:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/tradeoffer\/new\/\?partner=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $url, $matches);
if(count($matches)>0) 
{
    // this meets your criteria
}
```

Comment: awesome, but partner and token can be numeric, alpha (uppercase and lowercase).

Comment: What symbols? It would be much easier to help you if you didn't modify your question as we go... Next time you ask a question, remember that these specifics matter... we're taking time out of our day to help you, we should not have to jump through hoops to help you.

Comment: it can be: a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Comment: @mateuszji you should update the question so it reflects what you actually were trying to do.

Comment: I just edited the question for him to reflect the outcome