# PHP Regex that matches URLs without invalid characters

Tags: php, regex, string, url

I'm looking for a Regex that will find URLs in a string but ignore pre/following characters which are not part of the URL.

for example, from the string:

`example.co.uk (main site: example.com)`,

The Regex will find:

`example.co.uk` and `exaple.com`.

In order to find URLs within a given string, I use the Regex `'#(www\.|https?://)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}\S*#i'`.
The problem is that if I use this regex with the given string above, it finds `example.co.uk` and `example.com)` **with the closing bracket at the end.**

Is there any Regex that can find URLs in a string, not matter what characters it has from both sides?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url?rq=1

Comment: @AbdulHameed no, It's not a duplicate. His regex requires `http://`, and all the other comments does match the URLs with the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use a *[word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`)* ...

```
(?:www\.|https?:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}\S*\b
                                                  ^
```

**[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rw77Y8/1)**

Comment: Thank you so much!