# domain validate in php using preg_match

Tags: php

i want to validate the domain name in php using preg_match

For example these are all valid:

```
https://www.google.com 
http://www.google.com 
www.google.com 
google.com 
google.com/ 
https://www.google.com.tr/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=web+ui&
```

i can validate following example only

```
https://www.google.com 
http://www.google.com 
www.google.com 
google.com 

$domain_validation = "/(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[a-z]{2,63}|[a-z0-9]{2,59})?(?:\/)+$/i";
if(preg_match("$domain_validation", $inputDomainName)){
     $validSite = true;
}
```

and i want to validate this

```
google.com/ 
https://www.google.com.tr/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=web+ui&
```

Please help to solve

Comment: What about [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) With `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL `? See: [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url/207627#207627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. It should do exactly what you want.

```
$domain_validation = '/((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\&\.\/\?\:@\-_=#])*/';
if(preg_match("$domain_validation", $inputDomainName)){
    $validSite = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function

```
function getDomain($url) {
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Above function return domain with extension

***Example:*** It will return `google.com` if you pass any thing even with subdomain `mail.google.com or any www.google.com/images/xyz`

Then you pass any url to this function it returns you the domain with extension (.com, .net, .in whatever) and you can check with your inputdomain and validate simple.

Hope this helps