# How to make html link with php regex

Tags: php, regex

My string

```
[[https://example.com|link]]
```

to convert

```
<a href="https://example.com>link</a>
```

My regex is

```
/\[{2}(.*?)\|(.*?)\]{2}/s
```

But it's not working.I am new to php regex.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Comment: Use the capturing groups in the replacement https://regex101.com/r/riLKnf/1 You could also use negated character classes instead `\[{2}([^][|]*)\|([^][]*)\]{2}` https://regex101.com/r/qvY503/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~\[\[((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)\|(.*?)]]~s', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hgRDCv/1)

**Details**

- `\[\[` - a `[[` substring
- `((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value inside this group): any char (`.`), 0 or more occurrences but as few as possible (`*?`), that does not start a `[[` char sequence (`(?!\[\[)`)
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 (`$2`):
- `]]` - a `]]` substring.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/YJ2eQ):

```
$string = "[[some_non-matching_text]] [[https://example.com|link]] [[this is not matching either]] [[http://example2.com|link2]]";
echo preg_replace('~\[\[((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)\|(.*?)]]~s', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $string);
// => [[some_non-matching_text]] <a href="https://example.com">link</a> [[this is not matching either]] <a href="http://example2.com">link2</a>
```