# how to make html image markup using regex php

Tags: php, regex

My string contains

```
    [[image.jpg(alt)]]
```

And I need replacement

```
    <img src="image.jpg" 
    alt="alt"/>
```

My working regex

```
    /\[\[(.*?)\.{1} 
   (jpg|png|jpeg|gif)\ 
   ((.*?)\)\]\]/s
```

This Regex is working but i want a better Regex with additional values(example:width)

I need this string

```
    [[image.jpg|alt|100]]
```

Converted to this

```
    <img src="image.jpg' 
    style="width:100px" 
    alt="alt"/>
```

With Regex

```
    I seek help for this 
    from you guys
```

Comment: Why not use the same mechanism? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071810/how-to-make-html-link-with-php-regex

Comment: May be it will create conflicts with eachother using the same mechanism?

Comment: How do you know the second value is `alt` and the third one  is `style` for width? What are the specs?

Answer (score 0):

Mabe you should simply use explode ?

```
explode('|', 'image.jpg|alt|100');
```

Edit:
Quick example. Assuming your tags are valid. Use Regex to extract tags, then juste explode it to have values.

```
$text = 'qesrtdhyfugihseqs [[image.jpg|alt|100]] zqrestduhzeqmo qzeomphuzer qzeirgh [[image2.jpg|alt2|200]]';

preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*)\]\]/U', $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $image) {
        $imageAttributes = explode('|', $image);
        var_dump($imageAttributes);
}
```

Comment: I like regex ..And  is it posible to use explode if the string is like this? "normal paragraph [[image.png|alt|100]] anothe normal paragraph ...........

Comment: Regex are often an overkill solution, use it only if you don't have an other option.
Answer updated with full example for extracting tags and then your data;